# How optimised is CAML queries in Moss 2007, specifically with multiple DFWPs on the page

Tags: 2007, data-form-web-part

I have created a linked data source of two lists:

- Pages
- News categories (custom list)

Because there are no more than 5 news categories in the second list I am confident that my XSL won't have any problems in finding the News category associated with the Page efficiently. My page content type has a lookup property on the News category list, so this is what I'm filtering the News categories on.

However this has raised a query in my head. If I was to have multiple of these DFWPs on the same page doing very similar queries, or in the case of the News category list the exact same query, is there anything in SP that optimizes this? Is the XML of the list heavily cached to begin with so the query cost negligible?

In general some information on out of the box optimizations that may occur when doing CAML queries using SPDataSources would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of links that might help you

http://sharing-the-experience.blogspot.com/2012/06/performance-issue-caml-against-large.html 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798465.aspx

Comment: Please add some details with the links.Links can break and future user who will try to find the answer will no longer able access the link

Comment: I'm not concerned with the size of the list really, I'm more concerned with the fact that the same query will occur on a list 4-5 times in the same page. Ideally I'd like to re-use the same datasource but I don't think that's possible?